# How to get iBeacon Notification when the app is in Background mode in ios 10 and above?

Tags: objective-c

I have implemented iBeacon Notification in iOS 10 using objective-c. Can some one help me solve this problem to get the iBeacon in background mode in ios 10?

Comment: post some code here what you have acheived so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the app is not running, location events (related to the beacons in this case) are handled the same way as any other app launching events. Every time a phone enters or exits a region while the app is terminated, it will be automatically launched.

**application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** method (of **AppDelegate class**) is called with **UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey** key existing in launchOptions parameter.

When you verify this key exists (so location was the reason that your app was launched) you should create new instance of ESTBeaconManager class, set delegate to AppDelegate object (or any other object that is working as ESTBeaconManagerDelegate and was created before this event occurred) and start monitoring.

Region you are passing to the **startMonitoringForRegion**: method is not important, as **ESTBeaconManager** delegate will receive the most recent region information. You can just pick any of the ones your app registered in iOS. After Monitoring is revoked, app will automatically receive most recent entered/exited region event in **beaconManager:didEnterRegion**: or **beaconManager:didExitRegion:** method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ 
  if([launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey"])
  {
    self.beaconManager = [ESTBeaconManager new];
    self.beaconManager.delegate = self;
    // don't forget the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in your Info.plist
    [self.beaconManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [self.beaconManager startMonitoringForRegion:[[ESTBeaconRegion alloc]
                                                  initWithProximityUUID:ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID
                                                  identifier:@"AppRegion"]];
  }
  return YES;
}

-(void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region
{
  UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  notification.alertBody = @"Enter region";
  notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}

-(void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager didExitRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region
{
  UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  notification.alertBody = @"Exit region";
  notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}
```

Comment: These methods have been already added but still its not working.

Comment: Then what happen is there is any error. be specific